# scraping google search results page data python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, python-requests

i want to scrape emails on search resulted query. but when i access to class with css selecter "select" and print it always shows empty list. How can i access .r class or "class=g"?

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQA4leQETe0psVZPu7daLWbdsc9Ow%3A1579194494737&ei=fpggXpvRLMakwQKkqpSICg&q=%22computer+science+%22%22usa%22+%22%40yahoo.com%22&oq=%22computer+science+%22%22usa%22+%22%40yahoo.com%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0..7407...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.82okhpdJLYg&ved=0ahUKEwibiI_3zYjnAhVGUlAKHSQVBaEQ4dUDCAs"
    responce = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, "html.parser")
    test = soup.select('.r')
    print(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is correct, but to get correct answer from Google, you need to specify `User-Agent` header:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQA4leQETe0psVZPu7daLWbdsc9Ow%3A1579194494737&ei=fpggXpvRLMakwQKkqpSICg&q=%22computer+science+%22%22usa%22+%22%40yahoo.com%22&oq=%22computer+science+%22%22usa%22+%22%40yahoo.com%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0..7407...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.82okhpdJLYg&ved=0ahUKEwibiI_3zYjnAhVGUlAKHSQVBaEQ4dUDCAs"

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'}

responce = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  # <-- specify custom header
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, "html.parser")
test = soup.select('.r')
print(test)
```

Prints:

```
[<div class="r"><a href="https://www.yahoo.com/news/11-course-complete-computer-science-171322233.html" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AOvVaw2wM4TUxc_4V7s9GjeWTNAG','','2ahUKEwjt17Kk-YjnAhW2R0EAHcnsC3QQFjAAegQIAxAB','','',event)"><div class="TbwUpd"><img alt="https://...
...
```

Comment: Thanks .. 

my code's goal is to scrap emails on resulted quiery shown on google page.
i got text in ".st" class. but this text kind of raw. how i can filtered the text and get the exact email.

Answer (score 0):

To get the emails out of the Google Search results you need to use `regex`

```py
# this regex needs possible modifications
re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', variable_where_to_search_from)
```

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, re

headers = {
    "User-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    "Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q="computer science ""usa" "@yahoo.com"', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')


for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
    try:
        snippet = result.select_one('.lyLwlc').text
    except:
        snippet = None

    match_email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', str(snippet))
    email = '\n'.join(match_email).strip()
    print(email)

----------
'''
ahmed_733@yahoo.com
yjzou@uguam.uog
yzou2002@yahoo.com
...
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

It doesn't extract emails using regex although it would be a great possible feature. The main difference is that much easier and faster to get things done rather than creating everything from scratch.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import re

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": '"computer science ""usa" "@yahoo.com"',
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
    try:
        snippet = result['snippet']
    except:
        snippet = None

    match_email = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', str(snippet))
    email = '\n'.join(match_email).strip()
    print(email)

---------
'''
shaikotweb@yahoo.com
ahmed_733@yahoo.com
RPeterson@L1id.com
rj_peterson@yahoo.com
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.